Date modified does not change when copying existing file using FileInfo
I am using SSIS script task to copy a file from source directory to destination directory.
It works well when:
a. The source file is new and it does not exist in destination.
b. The file exists in both source and destination (with the same file mask) but its contents are different.
However, when:
c. The file is identical in both source and destination (with same mask and contents but with more recent timestamp in source), the code executes succesfully but the date modified timestamp remains unchanged in destination. As a result, I am unable to deduce whether it internally looked at the checksum and did not overwrite the file in destination as both files were same? Or it did overwrite but retained the timestamp because the checksum is same?
In either case, it seems to be looking at the checksum because only when the files are same does this happen. In other cases where the file contents are altered a little bit (keeping even the same file size) the overwrite happens as expected with the date modified reflecting source time.
Here is the code in the script task:
DirectoryInfo dSource = new DirectoryInfo(strSource);                                
foreach (FileInfo fi in dSource.GetFiles())
{
  if (fi.Name.Contains(strFile) && fi.Name.EndsWith(strExtn) 
  {                                      
    fi.CopyTo(strDest + fi.Name, true);
  }
}

To summarize: When copying a file from source to destination when the destination has an existing file with the same name, contents and size but with different timestamps - the override does not seem to happen even though the overwrite parameter is set to true in the FileInfo.CopyTo() method.
I tried this in another system but could not reproduce this behavior. So not sure if it is a Windows setting I should be looking at?

Try copying in Windows with File Explorer.  File dates do not change unless the file is opened and copy does not open the file.

Yes but here I am expecting the file in destination to be overwritten and have the same date modified as source. When both the files in source and destination are identical, the overwrite does not seem to happen and the destination file continues to retain its older timestamp.
Copy/paste using File Explorer gives me the prompt to overwrite and when I choose it, it overwrites the file and the timestamp in destination changes to what is in source. This is what I expect in the script task as well.

When I run your code I get the same behavior as copying using File Explorer. The "Created Date" of the destination file stays the same, but the "Modified Date" is updated to the match the modified date of the source.

Yes even I got the expected behavior in one system but this behavior is observed in another. I was not able to reproduce it. Makes me think if it is some underlying Windows setting.
